# How to neaten a text file and sort it whilst leaving the header at the top

Tags: bash, sorting

I have a text file that reads:

```
Name    Local   International   Total

Victoria University 17969   9199    27168

University of Wollongong    18194   12360   30554

University of Western Sydney    37531   4333    41864

University of Western Australia 20596   5241    25837

University of Technology Sydney 27584   10054   37638

University of Tasmania  21940   4872    26812

University of Sydney    42028   12278   54306

University of Sunshine Coast    9546    1210    10756

University of Southern Queensland   21536   5183    26719

University of South Australia   25520   7428    32948

University of Queensland    37252   11519   48771

University of Notre Dame Australia  10633   327 10960
```

There are also more lines of universities, but I'm assuming you don't need to read all of them all -- you get the idea.

I want to sort the text file in bash by the number of international students, whilst keeping the header at the top line.

Also if I can incorporate neatening the text file so the columns line up, that would also be good. But I'm unsure how to do that.

I have researched and I tried these, but neither worked:

1. ```
   cat q2.txt | (read -r; printf "%s\n" "$REPLY"; sort -nk3)
   ```
2. ```
   head -n 1 q2.txt && tail -n +2 q2.txt | sort -nr -k1
   ```

(The name of the file above is `q2.txt`.)

Comment: Which column is the number of international students?

Comment: @robert One problem is that the lines don't have a fixed number of fields: "Victoria University" is two words, while "University of Wollongong" is three. Fields must be counted from the end of line (right-to-left).

Comment: Is your file tab delimited?

Answer (score 0):

This problem is more suited to awk or perl; anyway I wrote this script, not well tested and probably with lot of room for improvements. Basically, it reads the file in memory to be able to cope with fields. Then, it constructs a file (named neattmpsort) to be processed by sort, then it reads back the ordered indexes to print out the final sorted table. There are comments in the script, and some debug instructions (as it is the first time I use arrays in bash).

```
# use 4 arrays to store name, nloc, ninter, ntotal
declare -a name
declare -a nloc
declare -a ninter
declare -a ntotal

nrecord=0
while read -a line; do
  let nrecord=$nrecord+1
  # echo "$nrecord: ${line[*]}"
  # assign fields. calculate number of words
  nfields=${#line[@]}
  let nfields=$nfields-1
  ntotal[$nrecord]=${line[$nfields]}
  let nfields=$nfields-1
  ninter[$nrecord]=${line[$nfields]}
  let nfields=$nfields-1
  nloc[$nrecord]=${line[$nfields]}
  #let nfields=$nfields-1
  uniname="${line[@]:0:$nfields}"
  # echo "uniname: $uniname"
  name[$nrecord]="$uniname"

  # echo "nloc=${nloc[2]} ninter=${ninter[2]} ntotal=${ntotal[2]}"
done < q2.txt

# now the file is read in. Construct a special file to
# be processed by sort, using ninter
[ -f neattmpsort ] && rm neattmpsort
for (( i=2; i<=${#ninter[@]}; i++ )); do
  echo "${ninter[$i]} $i" >> neattmpsort
done
# sort this file, which contains ninter and original record
# also read back the correct positions
declare -a sorted
while read sortkey origrec; do
  sorted+=($origrec)
  #echo "read sort $origrec"
done < <(sort -n neattmpsort)

#echo "sorted: ${sorted[@]}"
#read key

# now the final output
# header
echo -e "Name \t\t\t\t\t Local \t International \t Total"
for (( i=1; i<=${#sorted[@]}; i++ )); do
  kp=${sorted[$i]}
  # format name
  uniname="${name[$kp]}"
  while [ ${#uniname} -lt 36 ]; do uniname="$uniname "; done
  echo -ne "$uniname \t"
  echo -en " ${nloc[$kp]} \t"
  echo -en " ${ninter[$kp]} \t\t"
  echo -e  " ${ntotal[$kp]}"
done
```

The result with the data above is:

```
Name                                     Local   International   Total  
University of Sunshine Coast             9546    1210            10756  
University of Western Sydney             37531   4333            41864
University of Tasmania                   21940   4872            26812
University of Southern Queensland        21536   5183            26719
University of Western Australia          20596   5241            25837
...
```

I hope it helps. By modifying the script it is possible to format differently the output.

Answer (score 0):

First I printed a colon before each of the last three field from right, using the colon as a field separator we can sort based of the third field, and finally I deleted the colon from the output:

```
HEADER=`head -1 input.txt | sed 's/\s\+/;/g'`
BODY=`cat input.txt | awk 'BEGIN { ORS="" } NR>1 && NF{ for(i=1;i<=NF;i++){if(i > NF-3) print ";"$i" "; else print $i" "} print "\n" }' | sort -t';' -k3 -n`
echo -e "$HEADER\n$BODY" | column -t -s';'
```

The header is saved, and printed separately at the end.

Output:

```
Name                                Local   International  Total
University of Sunshine Coast        9546    1210           10756 
University of Western Sydney        37531   4333           41864 
University of Tasmania              21940   4872           26812 
University of Southern Queensland   21536   5183           26719 
University of Western Australia     20596   5241           25837 
Victoria University                 17969   9199           27168 
University of Technology Sydney     27584   10054          37638 
University of Sydney                42028   12278          54306 
University of Wollongong            18194   12360          30554
```

Answer (score 0):

```
sed -r '1{s/ +/;/g};2,${/./s/ +([0-9])/;\1/g}' file | sort -n -t';' -k3 | column -t -s';'
```

Not pretty, but it works :)

Explanation:

-r :- allows you to perform grouping with () without escaping them.  Also to use + without escape

1{s/ +/;/g} :- Change all collections of one or more lots of white space into a semi-colon for line 1

2,${...} :- from second line until the end of the file do everything between {}

/./ :- Only consider non-empty lines

s/ +([0-9])/;\1/g :- Assuming above is true, find 1 or more spaces followed by a group of number (save the numbers) and replace with a semi-colon followed by the saved numbers

sort -n -t';' -k3 :- Numerically sort by the third field delimited by semi-colons

column -t -s';' :- Create a table of columns using semi-colon as the delimiter to line data up on

Comment: Reading one liners is hard, can you add a little explanation? It is a corner case, but will this work if the university name contains a number field?

Comment: @robert - the edge case would also need to have the number preceded by white space.  So something like "University 2" or "University of 2nd Class".  As with most solutions, you can probably find an edge case it won't solve :)